# how to understand re.match in python?

Tags: python, regex

I have following python code:

```
import re

result = re.match('a.*b', 'aabab')
result.groups() # result is ()
len(result.groups()) # it's 0

result.group(0) # result is 'aabab'
```

I only know some basic `regex`, but I can not understand the `groups` and `group`. Could someone give some basic explanation about this.

and more, please give some explanation about `Pattern` and `Matcher` in python if possible.

Comment: Have you read [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/regex.html)?

Comment: mores specifically, the docs on the re library [`Match Object`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#match-objects)

Comment: Take a look at my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21249114/3182836

Comment: @MattDMo: Your link is 404...

Comment: @MattDMo , I didn't read. My problem is that I lack the knowledge of `Grouping and capturing` in regex.  I wanted to get some simple words to explain, but I read the doc. I understand it now, thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Groups are used to capture specific parts of a regular expression.  Your regex does not define any groups, therefore the group count is zero.

group(0) is a special case, and it contains the entire match.